# Why can't there be an "outside loop" in a perfectly insulated container with infinite time?

Tags: physical-chemistry

So I am having this arguement with my brother and wanted to ask other people.
It might be more of a chemistry question but Why can't there be an "outside loop" in a perfectly insulated container with infinite time?

So lets say we take a perfectly insulated container and place some matter in it, is it theoretically possible for the following to happen:
At time 0 when we start we have the first state which we'll call "state A", after some time X passes we will get another state which we'll call "state B", and after even more time Y we we'll get a new state called C.
Is it possible from then on out to get a loop only from state C to state B without ever reaching state A? If so then why? And if not then why?
Again it is inside a perfecly insulated container without outside interference, and there is an infinite amount of time.

Comment: Can you clarify how you tell two states apart? For instance, if I have a swinging pendulum, is the pendulum being on the way up a different state from when it is on the way down? Do you means state as QM, an eigenstate of a Hamiltonian?

Comment: So think about it as if you are to stop time and look at the situation, that is a state. So if you were to stop a pendulum on the way up and the way down in the same place then it may be considered the same state

Comment: I am not familiar with the formal side of physics so I don't know what are eigenstates of a Hamiltonian.

Comment: I think it is hard to answer this question because of this lack of clarity I'm afraid. If I put a gas inside the container at some finite temperature, all the gas particles will buzz around, changing their portions and velocities all the time. Does that mean that every second the gas is in a new state?

Comment: I do not believe your question as asked can be answered. Going from $A$ to $B$ itself is unverifiable in a finite time, the only thing you can measure is if going from $A$ meaning that from within an error defined by some $\alpha$ neighborhood of it to the state $B$ that is within some $\beta$ error of it. Only this can be verified in a finite time. Nobody has any idea what may mean to be anything after an infinitely long time, certainly not in an experimentally verifiable way. Can you now rephrase your question to make it answerable?